# online and offline status users in uitableview quickblox

Tags: ios, uitableview, chat, quickblox, offline-mode

I found this tuto that explain how to get offline/online status for one users but my purpose is to get status of my list of Users that's why when I tried to put

```
[QBUsers userWithID:usercell.ID delegate:self];
```

in my cellforrow I get many responses from webservice I don't know how to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

To get the realtime online/offline status of users you can use ContactList CHAT API http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios#Contact_list

You should create a datasource for your table, for example an array of users.

When you receive an update for a status of some user to this callback - you should update your datasource, for example something like this

```
- (void)chatDidReceiveContactItemActivity:(NSUInteger)userID isOnline:(BOOL)isOnline status:(NSString *)status{
     User *user = [self.myDataSource userWithID:userID];
     user.online = isOnline;

     [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```